# Convert bytestring to float in python

Tags: python, floating-point, mmap

I am working on a project where I read data which is written into memory by a Delphi/Pascal program using memory mapping on a Windows PC. I am now mapping the memory again using pythons mmap and the handle given by the other program and as expected get back a bytestring.

I know that this should represent 13 8-byte floating-point numbers but I do not know how I could correctly convert this bytestring back into those. I also know the aproximate value of the floating-point numbers to check my results.

The code I am using to get the bytestring looks like this:

```
import mmap
import time

size_map = 13*8
mmf_name = "MMF"
mm = mmap.mmap(-1, size_map, mmf_name, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

while True:
    mm.seek(0)
    mmf = mm.read()
    print(mmf)
    
    time.sleep(0.04)
    
mm.close()
```

For now I am just running the code again every 40 ms because the data is written every 40 ms into memory.

The output looks something like this:

```
b'\xcd\xcc\xcc\xe0\xe6v\xb9\xbf\x9a\x99\x99!F\xcd&@\xf5\xa2\xc5,.\xaf\xbd\xbf\x95\xb0\xea\xb5\xae\n\xd9?333/\x9b\x165@\x00\x00\x00h\x89D1\xc08\xd1\xc3\xc3\x92\x82\xf7?tA\x8fB\xd6G\x04@]\xc1\xed\x98rA\x07@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x191@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xcc\xcc=@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x1eE7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x1e\x1a@'
```

I tried `struct.unpack()`, `.decode()` and `float.fromhex()` to somehow get back the right value but it didn't work. For example the first 8 bytes should roughly represent a value between -0.071 and -0.090.

The problem seems to be very basic but I still wasn't able to figure it out by now. I would be very grateful for any suggestions how to deal with this and get the right floating-point values from a bytestring. If I am missing any needed Information I am of course willing do give that too.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you implement the 3 methods in your code? And as for "it didn't work", what did it return?

Comment: `struct.unpack` is the function you want. But you may have to be explicit about byte-endianness. On my machine, `struct.unpack("d", b'\xcd\xcc\xcc\xe0\xe6v\xb9\xbf')` returns `(-0.0994..., )`, but you can use `struct.unpack("<d", ...)` if necessary.

Comment: Unpack all 13 values with `struct.unpack("<13d", b'...')`.

Comment: Thanks for your help this works! Seems that I at least headed the right direction  with `struct.unpack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `numpy`s `frompuffer` function. You will get an array you can than read:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html

```py
import numpy as np

buffer = b'\xcd\xcc\xcc\xe0\xe6v\xb9\xbf\x9a\x99\x99!F\xcd&@\xf5\xa2\xc5,.\xaf\xbd\xbf\x95\xb0\xea\xb5\xae\n\xd9?333/\x9b\x165@\x00\x00\x00h\x89D1\xc08\xd1\xc3\xc3\x92\x82\xf7?tA\x8fB\xd6G\x04@]\xc1\xed\x98rA\x07@\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x191@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xcc\xcc=@\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x1eE7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x1e\x1a@'
nparray = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.float64)
nparray
```

> array([ -0.09947055,  11.40092568,  -0.11595429,   0.39127701,
> 21.08830543, -17.26772165,   1.46937825,   2.53507664,
> 2.90695686,  17.1       ,  29.79999924,  23.27000046,
> 6.52999878])

```py
nparray[0]
```

> -0.09947055

Comment: They're not asking about 8-bit values, but 8-*byte* values. Use `float64` instead.